# Calculating SOAP Content-Length

Tags: web-services, language-agnostic, soap

How do you calculate the Content-Length is a soap message?  Is it the number of chars in the whole soap message?

Answer (score 2):

Its the number of bytes, not the number of characters, so it will depend on the text encoding used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Convert your XML message to a string and use the length of the string as Content-Length.

(Assuming you are using eight-byte characters.)