# Soap content length

Tags: java, soap

I look at the following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request to SP server, but its does not matter.

```
POST /_vti_bin/lists.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.25
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetList"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetList xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <listName>string</listName>
    </GetList>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The field   *Content-Length: length* need to be replaced with actual values. What its value? Where is I can see it? Or how to calculate it value before request?

**UPD1.**
I use ksoap lib

```
 headerPropertyObj = new HeaderProperty("Content-Length", "383"); // should be calc before
 headerList.add(headerPropertyObj);

    transport.setUrl(URL);
    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

   request.addProperty("listName", "Tasks");


    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerList);
```

Comment: How are you creating your SOAP request?

Comment: This link may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290172/calculating-soap-content-length

Comment: I can see my full query in **transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerList);**, but I need calc content-length before this method.

Comment: It's an actual problem. Where is I can see xml code before call method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem. I wrote myself class

```
public class MyHttpTransportSE extends Transport
```

where is I reloaded call method like below

```
     public List call(String soapAction, SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope, List headers)
     throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

             if (soapAction == null)
                     soapAction = "\"\"";

             byte[] requestData = createRequestData(envelope);

             requestDump = debug ? new String(requestData) : null;
             responseDump = null;

             connection = getServiceConnection();

             connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "kSOAP/2.0");
//           connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", soapAction);
//           connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
             connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml");
             connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
             connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + requestData.length);
```

Its helped for me, I hope this helps for smb.

Answer (score 1):

The `Content-Length` value is the length (in bytes) of the body, which starts with the first `<` and ends with the last character of the body, here `>` or maybe a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the envelope the right way should be enough, without setting headers by yourself.

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); 
httpTransport.debug = true; //try debugging
```

If your problem relates to sharepoint authentication, then you should add envelope headers properly so the length keeps being calculated by the library itself. [Error in authentication when subscribing to a sharepoint webservice using ksoap2-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969107/error-in-authentication-when-subscribing-to-a-sharepoint-webservice-using-ksoap2)

this could help: http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/creating-sharepoint-list-items-with-php/

Comment: In my envelope header I must add a token from previous query. Token its a cookies with auth data to sharepoint server, without their I cant have other data.

Comment: I solved problem with authentication. I parse response from authentication wsdl, catch cookies and added there to the next query